# Magento2: create custom attribute description with wysiwyg editor in Category page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-attributes, wysiwyg, category-attribute

how to create custom attribute description with wysiwyg editor in Category page?
like this [image]

Comment: please check and update.

Answer (score 1):

how to get this field in phtml correctly?
I have problem, becouse i'm getting output like this:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $block->getCurrentCategory()->getAdditionDesc(), 'addition_desc') ?>

<p>test</p> <p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/moutures-uSelect-tailles-321x150.jpg"}}" alt=""></p>
```

and second:

```
<?php echo $block->getCurrentCategory()->getAdditionDesc(); ?>
```

in this one I have html correct but problem is with media, in browser img is like this:

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/moutures-uSelect-tailles-321x150.jpg"}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    //Category Attribute Create Script
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                'attribute_code',
                [
                        'group' => 'General',
                        'label' => 'Attribute Label',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'input' => 'textarea',
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 25,
                        'searchable' => true,
                        'comparable' => true,
                        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                        'visible_in_advanced_search' => true
                ]
            );
    $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me full detail ?

Comment: I update the answer, create "InstallData.php" in your extension and then put code there and then run upgrade and deploy commands.

Comment: can you give me category_form.xml file ?

Comment: why you want that one? There is not required of that one.

Comment: for admin inside showing

Comment: done above things, show this on "General" section on category page it self.

Comment: use that code but admin side not showing attribute and WYSIWYG editor

Comment: check, your attribute created on database or not. First need to remove extenison entry from the "Setup_Module" table and then run the commands and then check

Comment: i have checked in database but attribute not create

Comment: so remove entry from "setup_module" of your extension and then run the commands. confirm on above file you change the path with your extension.

Comment: thanks for support

Comment: If answer help you please upvote and accept as solution, it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /* category attribute */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'editor_data');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'editor_data',
            [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'label' => 'Content',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'input' => 'textarea',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 25,
                    'searchable' => true,
                    'comparable' => true,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'visible_in_advanced_search' => true

                ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="editor_data" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">editor_data</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">150px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Add Content</label>
                <dataScope>editor_data</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg>
                    <settings>
                        <rows>5</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: are you sure that `'input'    => 'boolean',` is correct?

Comment: i update my answer

Comment: when i insert a value and save the  refresh page attribute value will  null

Comment: plase check my answer i update  <item name="source" xsi:type="string">editor_data</item> line in xml file. now data are save and also show into edit mode

Comment: already change but attribute not create in database  that's why not insert value, any update ?

Comment: remove 'wysiwyg_enabled' => true, from InstallData.php and run upgrade command. also remove module entry from setup_module table.

Comment: thanks for support

Comment: please accept answer if it's helps you.